# Getting value for node in XML response to SOAP

Tags: xml, web-services, powershell, soap

I'm making a SOAP request in PowerShell like this:

```psh
$uri = "https://secure.echosign.com/services/EchoSignDocumentService20?WSDL"

$sun = Invoke-WebRequest $uri -Method post -ContentType "text/xml"  -InFile .\getUrl.xml
```

The "file" looks like this:

```xml
<api:getDocumentUrls>
  <api:apiKey>redacted</api:apiKey>
  <api:documentKey>REDACTED</api:documentKey>
  <api:options>
    <dto1:attachSupportingDocuments>true</dto1:attachSupportingDocuments> 
    <dto1:combine>true</dto1:combine>
    <dto1:auditReport>true</dto1:auditReport>    
  </api:options>
</api:getDocumentUrls>
```

I'm not getting any errors and the xml of the response as tested in SoapUI looks like this:

```xml
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <soap:Body>
    <ns1:getDocumentUrlsResponse xmlns:ns1="http://api.echosign">
      <ns1:getDocumentUrlsResult>
        <errorCode xmlns="http://dto14.api.echosign">OK</errorCode>
        <errorMessage xsi:nil="true" xmlns="http://dto14.api.echosign"/>
        <success xmlns="http://dto14.api.echosign">true</success>
        <supportingDocumentUrls xsi:nil="true" xmlns="http://dto14.api.echosign"/>
        <urls xmlns="http://dto14.api.echosign">
          <DocumentUrl>
            <name>test.pdf</name>
            <url>https://smuszconsulting.echosign.com/document/cp/2AAABLblqZhAOjW1Dv6ig0pMc1PaF5BSHiCNNVAU6PEBmVizdpa9kFwkX5wQurgfu7P0atiSKop4*/document.pdf</url>
          </DocumentUrl>
        </urls>
      </ns1:getDocumentUrlsResult>
    </ns1:getDocumentUrlsResponse>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I need to get that URL `DocumentUrl.url` into a variable so I can write it to a DB, but I can't figure out how.

I tried:

```psh
$newObj = $sun.getDocumentUrlsresponse.ChildNodes | % { $_.Name; $_.InnerText }
```

but that's not working. The object is not even created.

Ok ..I changed my code to look like this:

```psh
$uri = "https://secure.echosign.com/services/EchoSignDocumentService20?wsdl"

[xml]$sun = Invoke-WebRequest $uri -Method post -ContentType "text/xml"  -InFile .\getUrl.xml

$nsm = New-Object Xml.XmlNamespaceManager($sun.NameTable)
$nsm.AddNamespace('ns', 'http://dto14.api.echosign')
$url = $sun.SelectSingleNode('//ns:DocumentUrl/ns:url').innerText
```

Now I get this error:

```
Exception calling "SelectSingleNode" with "1" argument(s): "Namespace Manager
or XsltContext needed. This query has a prefix, variable, or user-defined
function."
At C:\Program Files\DCESS_InfoGatherer\testingGetUrl.ps1:53 char:1
+ $url = $sun.SelectSingleNode('//ns:DocumentUrl/ns:url').innerText
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException
```

Is there some way to see the XML in the response like I can using SoapUI?

I don't even really know if the response I'm getting is correct.

Comment: My bad. For some reason I failed to actually use the namespace manager after instantiating it. `$nsm` must be passed as the second parameter to `SelectSingleNode()`. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

The XML uses namespaces. The namespace in question is the defined on the `<urls>` node:

```xml
<urls xmlns="http://dto14.api.echosign">
```

The nested nodes use this namespace as their default namespace, so you need a namespace manager to access them.

```psh
[xml]$xml = $xmlResponseText  # turn the XML text into an XML object

$nsm = New-Object Xml.XmlNamespaceManager($xml.NameTable)
$nsm.AddNamespace('ns', 'http://dto14.api.echosign')
$url = $xml.SelectSingleNode('//ns:DocumentUrl/ns:url', $nsm).innerText
```

Comment: My first response lines are `<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" s:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
<s:Body><u:GetInfoResponse xmlns:u="urn:dslforum-org:service:WLANConfiguration:1">`. Can I apply your code or do I have to change `$nsm.addnamespace(..)` because I have `u:..` and `xmlns:u`. In `python`with `xmltodict` it works: `xml =xmltodict.parse(response.content.lower(), dict_constructor=dict);env = xml['s:envelope']..`